# setRouteVariables doesn't return errors to the template

Tags: plugin-development, validation

So I've been breaking my head trying to figure this out. I'm working on a contact form plugin. Basically I'm coping exact same code craft uses to create form "fields". I have validation working like it should. And I have 2 required fields that should return error messages. But when I try to:

```
craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
  'field' => $field
));
```

And in the template file {{ field }}, I get.. `Variable "field" does not exist`

I can't seem to get the value to populate on the form nor display the errors because of this. Anyone had problems like this before?

Here's my files:
https://gist.github.com/owldesign/e01b49fdb1da3ef23ef2

Sorry for weird file delivery.. this comment won't let me post more than 2 links.

Please let me know if you guys need more from me?
Thanks.

Edit: Repo https://github.com/owldesign/FormBuilder

Comment: can you just push up a repo fo the plugin to github?

Comment: here's a repo to the plugin https://github.com/owldesign/FormBuilder

Comment: does the error happen when first opening the field _edit screen, or only after making a new field with errors.

Comment: Error happens when I'm making the new field. I can't get the error messages from form validation to come through to the template. The flash message comes through but the variable "field" isn't coming through to the _edit.html template from the actionSaveField in the controller.

basically I'm trying to pass variable "field" to the _edit.html template from the controller using the setRouteVariables(), but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Have you tried moving the part where you return `craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables();` into the else statement along with the `craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('Field Not Saved.'));` part and then remove the `return` bit? This is how I have done this in the past and things return fine.

Comment: I have, I've done so much ah but nothing. Since validation works I'm going to have to figure out another way to display errors.

Comment: Are you sure the controller action getting called on the same request as the template that’s trying to output `{{ field }}` ? No redirect happening in between, etc.?

Comment: From what I can tell yeah, because I am still getting the flash message from the controller to the template.

Answer (score 1):

I have finished the plugin, with much success, if you wondering you can see it here https://github.com/roundhouse/FormBuilder-Craft-CMS